# How to place a youtube embedded link in a form?

Tags: php, youtube

I have a form where users can save an embedded youtube link. The link is saved to a mysql database and called on another page inside a modal. The form uses the link as a placeholder so users can see that they have completed this field when they return to the form. For some reason the acutal youtube clip is appearing inside the form rather than just the code.
How can I just display the code and not the video in the form?

```
 <label for = "video_clip">Video Clip</label>
     <input id="video_clip" name="video_clip" type="code" placeholder="<?php echo $video_clip;?>" value="<?php echo $video_clip;?>" >
```

Note: $video_clip is the embedded youtube link. Like this

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/EgdxIlSuB70" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: What is `$video_clip`?

Comment: That's the you tube link. I've edited my post.

Comment: Use single quotes in `placeholder` and `value` properties, like this: `... placeholder='<?php echo $video_clip;?>' value='<?php echo $video_clip;?>' >`

Comment: Quentin was quite right and the duplicate helped perfectly. Thanks.